# How to override the Spring @PropertySource order?

Tags: java, spring, config

The problem is that I have the database config file that has the "user" value and I am using the PropertySource and try to get that value but the SystemEnvironmentPropertySource took the priority which has the "user" value as well.

So how can I specify for the DBConfiguration class to use the database.config's user?

P.S - I can't change the config name as it is using by many applications.

```
@PropertySource("file:/config/database.config")
public class DBConfiguration {
  @Value("${user}")
  private String user;
  ..... 
}
```

Comment: 2023 - it's not possible

Answer (score 0):

My workaround is to use `ApplicationContextInitializer` and define the order explicitly:

```kotlin
open class OverrideApplicationContextInitializer: ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
    override fun initialize(applicationContext: ConfigurableApplicationContext) {
        if (applicationContext.environment.activeProfiles.contains("prod")) {
            try {
                val properties = Properties()
                properties.load(this.javaClass.getResourceAsStream("/my-prod.properties"))                applicationContext.environment.propertySources.addLast(PropertiesPropertySource("my-prod", properties))
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                logger.error(e.message, e)
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OverrideApplicationContextInitializer::class.java)
    }
}
```